# Type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

When I created a class, there is no existing namespace declaration and I need the namespace declaration to access the class from a view (cshtml).

Normally when you create a class, there should be a namespace declaration included right? But for me I don't see any.

I already tried to add a namespace declaration, but I still can't access it from another class.

I hope you could help me with this.

Screenshots: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5TGcf9mTeg2V2ZDaldWelp6WXc

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIw88.png)

Comment: Then, why don't you add a namespace?

Comment: I already added a namespace then clicked rebuild.

But when I access it from another class, it can't be found.

Comment: Let's see the other class code

Comment: If you've added or modified a class and want to use it in a view, you normally need to close the view and reopen it for Intellisense to pick it up. As long as you've recompiled, it would work regardless when you ran the project.

Comment: Try to look at the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5TGcf9mTeg2V2ZDaldWelp6WXc

I already closed all tabs even clicked rebuild and restarted visual studio, but it didn't work.

Comment: c# is case sensitve. PRL != Prl

Comment: Yes I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if it holds any impact, but close down everything, and try running as administrator for VS. Especially if you are trying to configure your project on a remote server location that you didn't setup yourself.

Comment: Yeah, thanks
It's already been solved.
Here is the link that I followed to make this possible.
 https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as what Nico Said (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5685258/nico)

Follow this instructions and this will be resolved:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget

Although I started all over again.

~I created a new project from Visual Studio 2017 using ASP.NET Web Application

~Selected an empty file

~ Right click on the project

~ Click Manage NuGet Packages and installed Umbraco CMS

~ Run it from VS and install the umbraco platform using the browser

~ As soon as I create a class, a namespace declaration will also be included.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

make sure your namespace name is correct .using PRL(Capitalized) .Models .And the good practice is add an empty web application **project** ,not a **website**.

Comment: I tried to use the Uppercase one, the lowercased and the pascal cased. All of them didn't work.
I am using umbraco cms, I don't have a choice to select the type of project that I will choose. Or do I? If there is a choice, how do you do that?

Comment: @MartinLloydJose create your cms base on an empty web application ,you can read official tutorial .[link](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget)

Comment: I will do, thanks, I will just make a comment back here if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your model belongs to namespace `PRL.Models` but you try `using Prl.Models` - namespaces are case-sensitive. Try `using PRL.Models`

**Edit**: and for the class without namespace-declaration: you should always have a class in a namespace. Declare one.

Comment: I already tried to make it uppercased, lowercased and pascal cased.
All of it didn't work well so far. I made the casing of the reference same as the namespace that I created, but it didn't work so far.

Comment: @MartinLloydJose So, first, get a structure the users of SO can work with - because this is one mistake you actualy did at the screenshot. Then make screenshots after eveything is fine, add the screenshots into your question and not into a google-drive. If you're changing the screenshots, the answeres are incorrect - if you are deleting the screenshots, nobody with the same problem can check if this is the same problem - this is not how SO works.

Comment: Sorry, I can't directly add more than 2 images here since I don't have enough reputation as what the stackoverflow error message given me earlier that's why I added it to the google drive instead.

Comment: I also didn't change the question, I just made it more detailed so that it would be more specific and can be understood easily. Sorry.

Comment: @MartinLloydJose Just sain' "if you change the screenshots" :)  - not the question. If you change the question the users can see, that you changed. That's why adding to SO is better than adding google drive :) - just a hint, cause you seem to be new to SO

Comment: Yeah I am new here. Thank you very much for the tip. Next time when SO allows me to upload more than 2 images, I will just upload it here directly. Thanks.